# Continuous Annuity Question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, finance, mathematical-modeling

I need to calculate the present value of a level continuous annuity which pays $1000/mo. for 10 years. The force of interest is 5/(3+2t). I tried taking the integral of e^(integral of force of interest from 0 to t) but I couldn't seem to come up with the correct answer. The answer in the back of the book is 11434.71, but I don't see how this is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Try integrating:

$$12000\int^{10}_0e^{-\int^t_05/(3+2r)dr}dt$$